# getting the list of modified/added/deleted files in two different tags using SVN

Tags: svn

I tried creating a sample repository and created two tags using the below link.
http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/svn/index.html.
I created two tags namely R1 and R2.

When I use a diff command like
diff ../tags/before-qt/ ../tags/after-qt/ it shows the files which got changed.

But when I try using SVN diff
svn diff -r file:///root/project/tags/before-qt/ file:///root/project/tags/after-qt/
It throws an error

My question:
1) whats the difference between diff and SVN diff commands

2) how can I get the list of modified files in a readable format(tried using summarize also. But its not working)

3) can diff be used on binary files. Will they be listed.

Comment: Are you running this under unix?  `diff` is a standard unix command... (type `man diff`)